# Which statistical test to compare between and within differences?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, treatment-effect, two-way

I have two groups of patients with two different treatments applied, Treatment A vs Treatment B. In addition, I have measurements on 4 different time points for an ordinal variable (scale 1 to 4, where 4 is worse than 1).

I would really appreciate if you could give me your insights about which statistical test or approach to use if I want to know between and within differences for the groups. I've been thinking on a Two-Way ANOVA but I am not sure at all.

Some ideas and discussion would be great!

Thank you very much!

Comment: That or a linear mixed model with random effects.

Comment: Question probably needs more details.